# Django app dependencies on Shared hosting(Cpanel)

Tags: python-3.x, django, cpanel, shared-hosting, google-cloud-automl

I've been trying to deploy an Django app in a Shared hosting with Cpanel.
But every time that I tried to install google-cloud-automl dependency I get this message on the server

```
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-vnlg73ta/grpcio/setup.py", line 212, in <module>
        if check_linker_need_libatomic():
      File "/tmp/pip-build-vnlg73ta/grpcio/setup.py", line 172, in check_linker_need_libatomic
        stderr=PIPE)
      File "/opt/alt/python37/lib64/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 800, in __init__
        restore_signals, start_new_session)
      File "/opt/alt/python37/lib64/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1551, in _execute_child
        raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
    PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'cc'
```

Any idea how I may install this dependency?

Answer (score 0):

It was the pip version used on my virtualenv so after updated it worked